# episerver cms integration with mvc5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, episerver

First of all I'm using Asp.net MVC5 Entity Framework 6 with code first database.

I want to ask about integrating Episerver CMS with mvc5 application to change content of the website, i have multiple questions:

1. Is it a good way to use Episerver to change the content, if my website is for articles and images(it's like news website)?
2. In deploying stage is there any issues(for those who use the Episerver extension).
3. If i'm using code-first sql server database, is there any issue with this?

I noticed that there is a useful explanation on youtube for this extension:

[Episerver CMS 9 tutorial with asp.net mvc 5 och twitter bootstrap 3 part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BbN7qrZp2z8&list=PLHv0omRXzUGq5925Kc8n-6LbI86r-1Mt8)

**the forth question, is there any better way to create CMS for MVC5 application.**

Answer (score 1):

If you implement Episerver CMS this will typically be your main application and content provider. Episerver is code first, Episerver uses EF, Episerver do support mvc5. Setup Episerver standalone and adapt and export your old datastructure and datamodel to fit that of a modern CMS.